# How do I associate native applications with file types in WINE

Tags: wine, file-association

The title says it all. I want to associate native applications with file types in WINE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Here is how you associate native applications in wine:

From the Wine [FAQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_associate_a_native_program_with_a_file_type_in_Wine.3F)

You can associate `winebrowser` with any file types to achieve the result. `winebrowser` program uses `xdg-open` to find the native application for a file type.

You need to create a registry file with these contents to associate `.pdf` files. Save it as `import.reg` file in your home folder.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf]
@="PDFfile"
"Content Type"="application/pdf"
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PDFfile\Shell\Open\command]
@="winebrowser \"%1\""
```

Now import the registry file using this command

```
regedit $HOME/pdf.reg
```

This will open pdf files from Wine applications with the native application which is set as *default* for a pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

A step by step instruction can be found here:
http://www.webupd8.org/2010/03/how-to-make-wine-open-links-in-your.html

You have to create for every file type first a corresponding ending like ".pptx" or ".mp4", associate it with "pptxfile" or "mp4file" under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT. 
pptxfile or mp4file then need the same registry entry shown above for

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\YOUR ASSOCIATED FILENAME\Shell\Open\command "winebrowser \"%1\"

The "associated filename" is pptxfile or mp4file, or whatever you have associated to the file type.